# Временно приостановить работы фоновых скриптов

Tags: php

У меня в фоновом режиме всегда работают несколько php приложений.
При запуске определенного скрипта, во время его выполнения, нужно приостановить работу всех других фоновых приложений.

Какие есть варианты для реализации ?

Answer (score 0):

Файловый мютекс может быть поможет. Его нужно всегда выполнять для проверки, можно-ли работать.

```
$fp = fopen("./fmutex", "w");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
  // работа
  flock($fp, LOCK_UN); }
fclose ( $fp ) ;
```